# How to merge a branch as if it were entirely a diff?

Tags: git

I have an issue where I am on feature branch A that was merged to master and deployed, but those changes had to be reverted due to some bugs. Afterwards I continued to work on branch A so it now has "original changes" and "fixes".

When I try to merge back to master though, "original changes" doesn't show up in the diff, only "fixes".

It's as if the revert takes priority over the branch because git knows that the revert happened after the base of branch A. Is there a way to have git (github) treat branchA as if it were branched fresh off the latest commit? The alternative is to create an entirely new branch and just manually copy over the files and changes from branch A.

Comment: You merged, then you reverted. There's no new change to merge: it was already merged, and found wanting and thrown out. If you want it back, the easiest way is to revert the revert—or (mostly) equivalent, cherry-pick the original commit to compute the original change and re-apply it.

Comment: Cherrypicking also occurred to me, but it's somewhat tedious given the number of commits. The branch would be trivial to merge if I could somehow get it to forget history and just treat the branch as a diff. I'm wondering if git has support for this feature.

Comment: Not directly, but that's what a `--no-ff` rebase is meant for. Reverting the revert remains simpler, but see https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt

Comment: Thank you, this describes the issue exactly!